# .isalpha prints as False but when checked, is True

Tags: python, passwords, alphanumeric, isalpha

This is part of a function used to check that a password is 9 characters long, alphanumeric, and contains at least 1 number. Ideally I should be able to use the first if statement but strangely, it doesn't run. I can't figure out why test1.isalpha runs as 'True' in the if statement but prints as 'False'.

```
test1 = 'abcd12345'

if len(test1) == 9 and test1.isalnum and not(test1.isalpha)
    print('This should work.')



if len(test1) == 9 and test1.isalnum:
    if (test1.isalpha):
        print('test1 is', test1.isalpha())

>>>('test1 is', False)
```

Comment: You are missing `()` after some of your method calls.

Answer (score 1):

In your if (`if (test1.isalpha):`) you are testing the method instance and not the result of this method.

You have to use `if (test1.isalpha()):` (parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `if test1.isalpha()` instead of `if test1.isalpha`

`test1.isalpha` is a method, And `test1.isalpha()` will return a result `True` or `False`. When you check with if condition method will always satisfied. And other one depends on result.

Look the diffidence.

```
In [13]: if test1.isalpha:
    print 'test'
else:
    print 'in else'
   ....:     
test

In [14]: if test1.isalpha():
    print 'test'
else:
    print 'in else'
   ....:     
in else
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

- `len(test1)==9` to ensure a length of 9
- `hasNumbers(inputString)` function to return `char.isdigit()` on any digit in the string
- `re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", test1)` to make sure there are only alpha and digit using [python re / regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re)

`import re
test1 = 'abcd12345'
def hasNumbers(inputString): 
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
if re.match("^[A-Za-z0-9]*$", test1) and hasNumbers(test1) and len(test1) == 9: 
    print('Huzzah!')`